# automatically insert text into java class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

If I create a new android activity, can I automatically insert a text into the java file that depends on the name of the class?

normally a java class is generated this way
[image: normally a java class is generated this way]

Can I set the java class to be generated this way, for example?
[image: Can I set the java class to be generated this way, for example?]

Comment: @BernoulliGate The [tag:android-studio] tag appears to be relevant here, as the question appears to be asking about changing how Android Studio is generating a class.

Answer (score 1):

Go File > Other Settings > Default Settings ...

There: Editor > File and Code Templates

Select Class (or other files) and add something like this:

```
public ${NAME} {
   Log.d(${NAME}, "log from constructor");
}
```

The specific case for Activity is in the tab 'Other' of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your IDE to do that. Eclipse is calling that "Code Templates" and can be configured globally or on a per-project basis. IBM provides a [tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-code-templates/index.html) but there are plenty of other resources out there if that is not helping enough.